Should an electronic ticket on the KTMB app be acceptable as proof of onward travel from Singapore to JB?
I'm flying to Singapore soon and will cross the causeway straight into Johor Bahru. The last several times I've flown into Singapore they've always wanted me to show proof that I'll be leaving Singapore before I can board the flight. At least Scoot always has done so.
I'm planning to travel overland around Malaysia then Thailand etc for months so I'm not going to have an onward flight booked. I'm planning to buy a train ticket to JB Sentral instead.
It seems the train is fully operational again unlike my last visit just at the end of the pandemic. I believe the train is Malaysian KTM and there isn't a Singaporean company. I can't figure out a way to buy a ticket on the KTM website. (Though there are at least two agents selling them online.)
But they do have an app, KTMB Mobile that foreigners can register with their passport details.
Will an electronic ticket bought on this KTMB Mobile app be acceptable as proof of onward travel when I board my Scoot flight in Australia?
I don't have my passport with me so can't register it yet to see if it has an option to print out the ticket, convert it to PDF, etc. I also don't know if there's a way to print a screenshot from an Android phone.

Beware that the KTM Shuttle Tebrau is extremely popular and can sell out weeks in advance: if you're flying out in a few days, it may be too late already to get a seat.

@lambshaanxy It's in nine days and it will be in the later evening, if that makes any difference.

Suggest you take a look, here's the special booking site for Shuttle services only: https://shuttleonline.ktmb.com.my/Home/Shuttle

@lambshaanxy Ah yes I did manage to find that page. Probably after I posted the question. I also need my passport to use it but for now they have hundreds of seats left after 9pm. I'm assuming this way will result in a printed ticket but can't check.

Yes. KTMB tickets are more than enough proof as a return ticket. You can also take shuttle bus tickets online from causeway link.
Being said that, you are unlikely to be asked to provide a return ticket when crossing the land border. Even if they asks, you can say that you plan to take bus to cross the border, which is a perfectly good answer.
I am not sure if its deployed on land border yet, but now everyone can use the automated gated to enter the country. You won't encounter an immigration officer when entering that way.

This is not to pass border control but to satisfy the airline OP has a ticket leaving the country.

Also, while I'm pretty sure a KTMB ticket would work with the airline, I'm asking specifically about an electronic ticket on my phone. I'll clarify that part of the question.

@hippietrail In that case, I had used the KTMB tickets as a proof of onward ticket. It would be wise to keep a printout.

As also in my question, I'm not sure if I can print a ticket from using their app or not.

@hippietrail Depends on airline agents. They probably will ask for printout. How about a screenshot?

If you book from here - https://shuttleonline.ktmb.com.my/Home/Shuttle , you will be able to print. You should get a PDF of ticket in mail.
